# LogRecord gives "<init>" as source method name

Tags: java, java-8, java.util.logging

A Legacy Application uses `java.util.logging` for logging. I needed some log to debug that app. I've used *FileHandler* as my log handler and written a formatter class for my custom log format.

While getting the method name(using `getSourceMethodName()`) for one of the `LogRecord`, I'm getting the method name as `<init>`. But there is no such method in the source code. What does this `<init>` actually mean ?.

Comment: it's the constructor if it's not clear enough from the duplicate

Comment: Thanks @Eugene :) BTW the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11789990/what-does-init-signify-in-a-java-exception doesn't have any accepted answer.